# how to copy a file and get name out of a file?

Tags: file, batch-file, dos

I have a file that I want to copy about 60 times. It has to be renamed, the names are saved in a .txt file.

Can I use a batch file for this?

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this...

Answer (score 0):

I´m not quite sure, if you are talking about Windows Command line window ...

But there are a lot of "commands" ... try `help for`.

If this doesn't help you, you can also use vbscript or powershell.